# Using JQuery in an AJAX control and avoiding conflicts

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery within a custom AJAX user control (part of a home grown toolkit) and I need to ensure that JQuery is present on the hosting page. There can be multiple instances of the control on a page and some controls may need to use different versions of JQuery.

At the moment I am using the following code to load in JQuery when the control initializes...

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page.GetType(), "jquery-1.4.4.min.js", this.ResolveUrl("TextControlPlugin/lib/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"));
```

This works because the scriptmanager handles not putting multiple copies of the same script into he page.

Problems...

- I cannot use JQuery statically in the
  calling page (I may not have a
  control on the page but need to use
  JQuery)
- The scriptmanager appears to
  handle only duplicate URL's and I
  will need to deploy it from
  potentially 2 different URL's (the
  calling page's copy and the controls
  copy)

So, is there a way to isolate a version of JQuery to the context of my control that doesnt interfear with any use of JQuery from the calling page? The developer writing the page may not have access to the internals of the control.

I have looked at JQuery.noConflict() but cannot seem to get it to work correctly - I believe I'm having problems with the order in which the scripts are injected into the page - I keep getting JQuery is undefined errors.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would there be a problem just taking a dependency on jQuery and putting it in your base MasterPage? This way, it would always be ensured to be in the page.

I'd recommend going for only one version of jQuery too as it will get confusing very quickly as to which variable refers to which version of jQuery. Passing `true` to `$.noConflict(true)` will assign what `jQuery` references to `_jQuery` and `_$`.

Comment: Hi mate! I could do that but then I would need to detect if the correct (i.e. latest) version was present and if not throw a control error. Any ideas on detecting the current version?

Comment: Got it - $().jquery;
 - cheers mate, I think this by far the most pragmatic approach :)

Comment: You can get the version of jQuery with `$.fn.jquery;`. Is your control tool kit intended to be used by a third party who may or may not include jQuery?

Comment: Why would you need a specific version? Are you using methods that may not potentially be in an older version of the library?

Comment: it more about plugin dependencies on specific versions but I should be able to get around that by using the latest version and your approach of sticking it in the masterpage. The only problem now is injecting the version checking code right at the top of the page containing the control. The idea was to make the toolkit as isolated as possible because it may be used in future by graphic designers, not programmers but I can live with this approach as long as I can shout at them for not including it and tell them what to do to fix it